# PayPal login button , prevent new window or close automatically?

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

I integrated PayPal button using the links below.
But it keeps opening a new mini-browser and after the login this browser remain open.

I would like to know how I do one of two (or both , even better)

1. Get the mini-browser to close automatically after the user logs in.
2. Prevent the new window and have the PayPal login in the original window.

These issues cause a bad user experience that I want to improve.

[PayPal Reference #1](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/identity/button/)

[PayPal Reference #2](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/identity/button-js-builder/)

[PayPal Reference #3](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/identity/ux/)

Answer (score 1):

For #1 on your return URL you can add following code:

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script>
      top.window.opener.location = 'http://example.com/';
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Include non-JavaScript content here -->
    If this page does not redirect <a href="page to deliver content to non-JS customer">Click Here</a>
  </body>
</html>`
```

You can refer to this link https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/digital-goods/ClosingWindow/

Search for Reloading Parent Page to a Specific URL